# How to put label to tuple and convert map by elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I would like to put label to tuple data.
I have following tuple data.

```
{"Bob","34","jp"}
```

Then I want to put label and make map.

```
%{name: "Bob", age: "34", from: "jp"}
```

I don't mind whatever labels come from. list or map or whatever else.

Please give me advice.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    members = 
    [{"Bob","34","jp"}, {"Geo","25","en"}, {"Cha","31","us"}]
       |> Enum.map(fn({n, a, f}) -> %{name: n, age: a, from: f} end)
```

It was easy.